# Typed navigation in jetpack compose returns the destination to the initial

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to make the main application appears after authentication. For navigation i use 'com.kiwi.navigation-compass is used.typed:core:0.6.2'. First, onAuth is called, the main application opens the dashboard then switches back to the auth screen and again calls onAuth. The main application does not use a navigation controller. There are no errors in the console. The same error was when I used non-typed navigation-compose. What did I do wrong?

MainActivity:

```
setContent {
    YandexMusicTheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = createRoutePattern<RootDestinations.Auth>(),
        ) {
            composable<RootDestinations.Auth> {
                AuthScreen({
                    navController.navigate(createRoutePattern<RootDestinations.MainApp>())
                })
            }
            navigation<RootDestinations.MainApp>(
                startDestination = createRoutePattern<MainAppDestinations.Dashboard>(),
            ) {
                mainAppRoute()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AuthScreen:

```
@Composable
fun AuthScreen(
    onAuth: () -> Unit,
    authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    LaunchedEffect(authViewModel) {
        authViewModel.onEvent(AuthEvent.StartAuth)
    }
    val state = authViewModel.liveData.observeAsState(authViewModel.initialState)
    when (state.value) {
        AuthState.Initializing -> LoadingView()
        AuthState.InitializingFailed -> SomethingWentWrongView()
        AuthState.LoginOpened, AuthState.InvalidLogin -> LoginView(failed = state.value is AuthState.InvalidLogin) {
            authViewModel.onEvent(AuthEvent.EnterLogin(it))
        }
        AuthState.PasswordOpened, AuthState.InvalidPassword -> PasswordView(failed = state.value is AuthState.InvalidPassword) {
            authViewModel.onEvent(AuthEvent.EnterPassword(it))
        }
        AuthState.AuthenticationOpened -> LoadingView()
        AuthState.AuthenticationError -> SomethingWentWrongView()
        AuthState.Authenticated -> onAuth()
    }
}
```